# button click/selection changed event in ag-grid with Angular2

Tags: angular, web-applications, grid, ag-grid

I am using **AG-Grid** in **Angular 2**. I have a `cellRenderer` function that creates a button. I need to fire a click action on the button click.

The function for my click is in my controller.

```
(click)="editClick(event)"  ---- doesn't fire
```

I know this can be achieved in **Angular 1.x** setting '`angularCompileRows=true`' in the gridOptions. Is there any equivalence in **Angular 2**?

Comment: put your code here

Comment: Can you try to change `event` to `$event`